# jQuery - triggerHandler Click => Write Cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Over a Frontpage i use a Colorbox. (Colorbox-Node Module - Drupal7)
In this Box opens a Klynt Project (http://www.klynt.net/) - like a Video.
To open it directly from the page view I use this script in a Block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.colorbox-node').triggerHandler("click");
        });

    // ]]>
 </script>
```

is it possible to hook a cookie so that 'click' would be triggered only once per user?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Herer you can see how to set and check cookie. Once the cookie is set you can handle your click. Keep in mind cookie can be attached to page and whole domain. So if you want the cookie on all pages attach it to domain. For more info see this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all use some cookie plugin of jQuery like this:
[jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Then just rewrite your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (!$.cookie('was_here') ) {
    $.cookie('was_here', true);
    $('.colorbox-node').triggerHandler("click");
  }
});
// ]]></script>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm, i write the jquery.cookie.js into the Drupal Theme.info
like this : scripts[] = js/jquery.cookie.js

Copy the file jquery.cookie.js into the js folder. 
...and use your script... 

but the Colorbox displayes every time..?!?

Comment: Are you sure cookie file get's added? Does browser console produce any error in this code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8082/sites/all/themes/my/js/jquery.cookie.js?mtbtem"></script>

Comment: In your browser, open your console(F12 most of the time) and watch network panel if your script does return 200 HTTP OK message or 404 NOT FOUND :)

Comment: can i do this with jstorage too ? - So i dont have to write a Coockie.
http://www.jstorage.info/